# What is the square at the left of an Inkscape text zone ?

Tags: textbox, inkscape

I noticed that there is a square looking like a handle on the left side of text boxes on Inkscape :

[the square on the text zones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1CQe.png)

But nothing happens when I click on it or when I try to drag it. I looked in the Inkscape manual, and this is what they say about handles on text boxes :

[explanations on Inkscape website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRZ9Z.png)

Did someone ever used this ? Or do you have any clue about what this could be ? I can't prevent myself from looking at it and this has killed my productivity ! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a *text anchor*, and it may be on left, center or right depending on text alignment. It is the position of the text element in the SVG file.

You can use it for aligning and snapping.

The other alignment / snapping feature for text is the *baseline*.

Comment: It doesn't seem to change position with the text alignment. But it does snap, thanks !